# Python Spark How to Map Fields of one rdd to another rdd

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am very new to python spark as per above subject i want to map the fields of one Rdd to the field of another Rdd.Here is the example

rdd1:

```
c_id    name 
121210  abc
121211  pqr
```

rdd2:

```
c_id   cn_id cn_value
121211  0     0
121210  0     1
```

So the matched c_id will replace by **name** with **cnid** and the aggregated the **cn_value**. So the output will like this  abc 0 0  pqr 0 1

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
import csv
sc = SparkContext("local", "spark-App")
file1 = sc.textFile('/home/hduser/sample.csv').map(lambda line:line.split(',')).filter(lambda line:len(line)>1)
file2 = sc.textFile('hdfs://localhost:9000/sample2/part-00000').map(lambda line:line.split(','))
file1_fields = file1.map(lambda x: (x[0],x[1]))
file2_fields = file2.map(lambda x: (x[0],x[1],float(x[2])))
```

How can i achieve my goal by putting some code here.

Any Help will highly appreciated
thanks you

Comment: There is an operation called `join` and a structure called [`DataFrame`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame). You should also take a look at [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv)

Comment: @mlk I wanted to give OP a chance to show some effort :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operation you're looking for is called `join`. Given a structure of your it is probably best to use [`DataFrames`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#dataframes) and [`spark-csv`](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv#python-api) (I assume that the second file is comma-separated as well, but has no header). Lets start with dummy data:

```
file1 = ... # path to the first file
file2 = ... # path to the second file

with open(file1, "w") as fw:
    fw.write("c_id,name\n121210,abc\n121211,pqr")

with open(file2, "w") as fw:
    fw.write("121211,0,0\n121210,0,1")
```

Read first file:

```
df1 = (sqlContext.read 
    .format('com.databricks.spark.csv')
    .options(header='true', inferSchema='true')
    .load(file1))
```

Load second file:

```
schema = StructType(
    [StructField(x, LongType(), False) for x in ("c_id", "cn_id", "cn_value")])

df2 = (sqlContext.read 
    .format('com.databricks.spark.csv')
    .schema(schema)
    .options(header='false')
    .load(file2))
```

Finally join:

```
combined = df1.join(df2, df1["c_id"] == df2["c_id"])
combined.show()

## +------+----+------+-----+--------+
## |  c_id|name|  c_id|cn_id|cn_value|
## +------+----+------+-----+--------+
## |121210| abc|121210|    0|       1|
## |121211| pqr|121211|    0|       0|
## +------+----+------+-----+--------+
```

**Edit**:

With RDDs you have you can do something like this:

```
file1_fields.join(file2_fields.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1:])))
```

Comment: Can we Implement it without using dataframe like Using Pure Spark Transformations and action. By making key and replace the c_id with name and aggregate the cn_value...

Comment: You can, but since your input is tabular it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Thanks , Data In file1 is comma-separated with multiple fields ,and data in file2 is also comma-separated  with only three fields but file2 is not csv. file2 is hdfs part file i have to map and aggregate the result of this two files.based on c_id from file1 and c_id from file2 then repalce c_id with respective name and aggregate result based on c_id and cn_id from file2.

Comment: file1_fields.join(file2_fields.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1:]))) this giving me the result like (u'121210',(u'abc', (u'0', 0))) can we remove these brackets and can get op like 121210,abc,0,0. please have look

Comment: `join` outputs following structure `(key, (value_left, value_right))`. This is a standard Python tuple so you can reshape it as you wish.