# How to reformat the Spark Python Output

Tags: python, apache-spark

```
(u'142578', (u'The-North-side-9890', (u'   12457896', 45.0)))
(u'124578', (u'The-West-side-9091', (u'   14578217', 0.0)))
```

This i got from Joining the two RDD based on Ids this is like **(key, (value_left, value_right))** by using this Spark Join.

so i want to have output like

```
The-North-side-9890,12457896,45.0
The-West-side-9091,14578217,0.0
```

for this i try with the following code

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext("local", "info")

file1 = sc.textFile('/home/hduser/join/part-00000').map(lambda line: line.split(','))
result = file1.map(lambda x: (x[1]+', '+x[2],float(x[3][:-3]))).reduceByKey(lambda a,b:a+b)
result = result.map(lambda x:x[0]+','+str(x[1]))
result = result.map(lambda x: x.lstrip('[(').rstrip(')]')).coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/finalop")
```

but giving me the following output

```
(u'The-North-side-9896',  (u'   12457896',0.0
(u'The-East-side-9876',  (u'  47125479',0.0
```

so i want to clean this how could i do that

help me to achieve this.

Comment: Could you please improve the example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34198439/python-spark-how-to-map-fields-of-one-rdd-to-another-rdd
refer to know moew about question

Comment: how can we remove ()u'u" . to get clean output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get from this:

`(u'142578', (u'The-North-side-9890', (u' 12457896', 45.0)))`

to this:

`The-North-side-9890,12457896,45.0`

you need to use:

```
result = result.map(lambda (k, (s, (n1, n2))): ','.join([s, str(int(n1)), str(float(n2))]))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
def rdd2string(t):
    def rdd2StringHelper(x):
        s = ''  
        if isinstance(x, collections.Iterable):
            for elem in x:
                s = s+str(rdd2StringHelper(elem))
            return s
        else:
            return str(x)+','

    return rdd2StringHelper(t)[:-1]

yourRDD.map(lambda x: rdd2string(x)).saveAsTextFile(...)
```

This function works for all kind of tuples that can be formed by any combination of tuples (tuple2, tuple3,tuple21,etc) and lists (lists of lists, lists of tuples, list of ints,etc) and outputs a flat representation as a string in CSV format.

It also answers your question from [How to remove unwanted stuff like (),[], single quotes from PyPpark output [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34944298/how-to-remove-unwanted-stuff-like-single-quotes-from-pyppark-output?noredirect=1#comment57622145_34944298)

**EDIT**

Do not forget to add this `import collections`

Comment: I would use `str.join` instead of `+` but here you are :)

Comment: Hi Radu lonescu, i am getting  this error                                UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment

Comment: Can you post a stacktrace?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hadoop/spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.4/example.py.py", line 245, in <module>
    sample('0',str(name),str(t1),str(t2),sc,"c")
  File "/home/jadoop/spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.4/new_sample.py", line 588, in sample2
    if isinstance(x, collections.Iterable):
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment

Comment: And you have this function header `def rdd2StringHelper(x):`?

Comment: @Radu.. yes i have have use your answer as it is

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101411/discussion-between-radu-ionescu-and-deno-george).